Can a Catholic be excommunicated for willful disregard of Church law?
This relates to a discussion on another Question (which I won't link because I don't want to draw attention to the OP). The following is all hypothetical. (I, personally, am not Roman Catholic, nor do I have any plans of becoming so.)
Let's say I engage in some practice which I believe to be beneficial to my health. (The specific practice is irrelevant.) Let's say, also, that the RCC forbids this practice. However, I believe that my health is more important than adhering to Catholic teaching, so I continue the practice in genuine belief that doing so is critical to my health and longevity.
Could I be excommunicated for this? Does it make a difference if I was already Catholic, vs. if I converted with the intention of ignoring the RCC prohibition to refrain from this practice?

Do you mean "could" in the broader theoretical possibility or more in the sense of does current Church law allow for a possibility?

@eques, either? I am not Catholic, but... does the RCC really not excommunicate people that willfully disobey the Church? That would seem to be a change from the Reformation days, if so.

Things have changed, but also things may not have been quite what you heard either.

If you are persisting in public, scandalous sin, you can be excommunicated by the competent authority. That competent authority would be whichever bishop(s) you are subject to, including the Pope. Usually, the bishops will try to take other steps to reconcile you publicly with the Church, such as having you give a public address where you repent of the persistent sin, or in the very common case of scandalous marital situations, convalidating an invalid marriage.
If you are persisting in private sin, you usually will not be excommunicated for that, although if your pastor knows and cares for your soul, he will encourage you to repent, to seek confession, and to refrain from communion until you repent. He also has the right to deny you communion if he has reason to believe you have not repented of some serious sin through confession.
When it comes to canon law, there are crimes which carry a penalty of excommunication latae sententiae, which is automatic. The linked article explains which sins canon law considers to carry a penalty of automatic excommunication, as well as required conditions for the excommunication to occur, but I will copy the list at the bottom of this answer.
In cases where an excommunication latae sententiae has occurred, the Church may wish to verify publicly that it has occurred, as happened in the case of Archbishop Marcel Lefebvre in the 1980s. The document Ecclesia Dei formally recognized that Lefebvre had been excommunicated latae sententiae, but the excommunication was effective the moment he broke the law.
Whenever an excommunication is public, whether because it was done to address a particular public scandal by the competent authority, or as verification that an excommunication latae sententiae took place, public reconciliation (not the sacrament) is required to restore communion. A competent authority (a bishop) must publicly declare that the excommunication has been lifted, and usually will require some public recanting of the scandalous behavior or opinions, or public repentance of the sin incurring excommunication latae sententiae. When it comes to private (that is, not publicly verified) excommunications latae sententiae, a bishop still must be the one to restore the excommunicated person, but need not do so publicly.
Your hypothetical actually applies to the canonical crime of procuring abortion, which according to current canon law incurs automatic excommunication. If the abortion is not publicly known, or the excommunication is not publicly verified, but the person met all the criteria for the excommunication latae sententiae to take hold at the time of the abortion, it is still the case that only a bishop can restore them to communion with the Catholic Church. However, the bishop can delegate this authority to his priests.
The following text is copied from the linked Catholic Answers article, accessed November 19, 2024

The 1983 Code of Canon Law attaches the penalty of automatic excommunication to the following actions:

Apostates, heretics, and schismatics (can. 1364)
Desecration of the Eucharist (can. 1382)
A person who physically attacks the pope (can. 1370)
A bishop who consecrates another bishop without papal mandate (can. 1387)
A priest who violates the seal of the confessional (can. 1386)
A person who procures an abortion (can. 1397 §2)
Accomplices who were needed to commit an action that has an automatic excommunication penalty (can. 1329)

In order for the penalty to be considered to apply, certain conditions must be met (cans. 1323–1324):

The individual must be at least sixteen years old.
The individual must know that his action was a violation of Church law.
The individual must have acted freely without threat of force or grave fear, have the use of reason, and not have acted mistakenly.



"He also has the right to deny you communion", isn't that what excommunication means?  Anyway, thanks for the Answer! I certainly agree any competent priest will attempt to remediate the situation short of that; for my Question, I'm interested in what could happen if those attempts have failed. In that case, I'm guessing he'd be likely to "deny you communion"?

Excommunication means the person is not within the Church formally, whereas denying communion refers specifically to refusing to let someone partake of that specific sacrament. Anyone who is excommunicated should not be receiving communion, but neither should someone who has committed grave sins that do not incur the penalty of excommunication who has not been to confession. Excommunication, moreover, is a legal status within the Church's code of ecclesial law, whereas a priest may deny someone communion for more broad reasons than strict violation of ecclesial laws.

@Matthew so say for instance that a Catholic makes use of IVF to conceive a child. This is not the kind of act that incurs excommunication formally under ecclesial law, but it is a mortal sin. That person's pastor should counsel him or her to seek forgiveness for that sin, and, if the pastor has good reason to believe the person under his care is unrepentant, he should deny him communion. The pastor, however, who is usually only a priest, has no authority to formally excommunicate his parishioner. Only the bishop can do that, and would need to do it by a formal and public decree

You must deny communion only when it would suggest the church agrees with a publicly known sin. You may not deny communion only based on your personal knowledge of a sin. The person asking for communion should, but now always does, refrain from communion in such a situation.

@ABMK canon law stipulates that ministers cannot deny Sacraments to those who seek them at appropriate times, are properly disposed to receive them, and are not prohibited by law from receiving them. If your priest knows that you are in unrepented mortal sin, he can deny you communion because he knows you are not properly disposed. He must deny you communion if the mortal sin is manifest, ie publicly known/knowable.

As I am a deacon, the question for me is not what my priest can or cannot do, but what I can or cannot do. In practice this matter does arise every now and then, and I follow what several bishops have told me. But I would be interested to see the rules, could you refer me to the relevant canons?

@ABMK your comment is not necessarily in disagreement with jaredad7's. It is not personal knowledge of sin, but persisting in a manifest grave sin. The reason for the canon is sorta because it implies an agreement with a publicly known sin, but that's not quite the same criteria.

@jaredad7 The case of abortion definitely fits the question. But what if it is a dietary restriction that someone believes is contrary to remaining healthful. Is a catholic then just trapped between "church laws" and "sinning by acting against their conscience"?

@ABMK I think you are correct that you are not able to make this call, but your pastor should be able to, as far as I am aware. This article, and other sources, too, indicate that canon law says what I said, but I am struggling to find the actual canon.

@ABMK My wife ran into this situation teaching religion at a Catholic high school with some students who were semi-public apostates (had told some friends, but weren't completely public with it). The pastor told her that he could deny communion, but that the extraordinary ministers could not, unless he directed them to. As you are an ordinary minister, I'm not sure exactly how this would pertain to you, but I think that the rule is that the pastor has discretion over denial and the direction of other ministers to deny.

@Wyrsa the Church excepts all dietary restrictions in the case that severe health complications would result from following the dietary laws, as far as I know, although for most people, there would not be serious complications. If any aren't excepted, the person can appeal to their bishop for a dispensation.

@jaredad7 I have a rather vulgar example as well as some other "foods" where I'm very certain the church would not approve even if the person is being sincere about how they felt it was required for their health. I believe the church side would be correct, as they would point to science and that the person was in error.

@jaredad7, as a deacon I am not an extraordinary minister indeed. But I am mostly interested in the canons on this matter. I have asked a priest of our diocees who is a specialist in canon law and he confirmed that communion cannot be refused based on a state of sin that is not publicly known. So I would like to read the canon that says otherwise very much.

@Wyrsa the Church isn't going to relax dietary restrictions just because of someone's personal opinion about their own health, nor should She. If a trusted medical professional can attest to the need to, say, practice a carnivore diet, then the bishop may (but is under no obligation to) relax the person's requirement to abstain from meat on Fridays. Best practice would probably be to give that person a different penance (or a number of penances to select from) with which to replace the abstinence requirement. As for other acts, if they are intrinsically evil, the Church cannot permit them.

@ABMK the vatican website is having issues with a bad gateway right now, but it appears the canon that I've seen reference in other sources and which I reference above is Can 843. Here is is a PDF hosted on a Diocesan website. My lay reading of the text seems to indicate a pastor (but not necessarily, though possibly, other ministers, ordinary or extraordinary) should not give communion to someone he knows is not properly disposed.

@ABMK as I've said, I have secondhand knowledge of a situation like this in practice, where the pastor seemed to indicate that the judgment call was his to make, rather than that no one could deny the person communion absolutely, though the sin was only known by some. However, if a canon lawyer disagrees, I would of course need to defer to his judgment, since I am not sufficiently educated on canon law to know where my interpretation might have gone wrong. That said, I would be interested in understanding why I am wrong. I think I'll open a question on this.

@jaredad7 Anyways your answer is insightful for the catholics. So many statutes and rules, so formal. But that is how it is. You basically said my point though. :)

@Wyrsa we have rules because the Church is an organization

@Wyrsa do you have an example of a dietary restriction the Catholic Church obliges on its member as a matter of strict morality that would even trigger the circumstance you describe?

@eques bodily fluids comes to mind, cannibalism comes to mind.

@Wyrsa I think it's fairly obvious that those would not entail dietary restrictions as such. Dietary restrictions would entail forbidding people to eat things that ordinarily count as food, either indefinitely or at specified times or in specified places. Consuming the bodily fluids of other human and cannibalism are intrinsically evil kinds of things. To quote one of the funniest lines in any fallout game "strictly speaking, we're no longer allowed to eat people."

@jaredad7 Haha, nice quote. Yeah my examples are borderline "obvious" evils, except it is accepted in some places. Which is weird to modern western folk. Regardless, nice comment chat about it. :)

@Wyrsa in re-reading your earlier comment about being trapped between Church laws and following one's conscience. The Church has no dietary laws which prohibit food as food categorically. There is restriction of times for food. However, more broadly, your concern is a core moral question -- the resolution between moral law/Church law and conscience (judgement of reason).

@eques Basically since the question about "not following your conscience is sin" and Aquinas' position on it was posed. I've been interested in that problem and how the catholics deal with it. The "eating blood" one is an example of this. Hence the interest in this quesiton

@Wyrsa often, when people who are not fully educated on moral theology speak of conscience, and especially when they dichotomize conscience and following the precepts and other laws of the Church, they will conceive of conscience in any state. However, orthodox moral theologians would near-universally give you the qualifier that a sin against conscience properly so-called is a sin against well-formed conscience. Well formed conscience cannot conflict with what the Church calls one to do or not do. Furthermore, we have a duty to seek to form our conscience well.

@Wyrsa I'm fairly certain we have questions here on following conscience per Aquinas.

@eques Yeah, I literally referred to those questions it in my previous comment :)
