According to current Canon Law, is a pastor permitted to deny communion to someone he privately knows to be in a state of grave sin?
Canon 843 says

Can. 843 §1. Sacred ministers cannot deny the sacraments to those
who seek them at appropriate times, are properly disposed, and are
not prohibited by law from receiving them.
§2. Pastors of souls and other members of the Christian faithful,
according to their respective ecclesiastical function, have the duty to
take care that those who seek the sacraments are prepared to receive
them by proper evangelization and catechetical instruction, attentive to
the norms issued by competent authority.

This seems to me to entail that priests may deny communion to those they know to be improperly disposed. If someone seeks communion at an inappropriate time, or while improperly disposed, or is prohibited by law from receiving communion, then there does not appear to be any requirement for the pastor to give that person communion.
Yet, there are those who say that a priest can only deny communion to someone who is in "manifest grave sin." This is a reference to canon 915, which says

Can. 915 Those who have been excommunicated or interdicted after the imposition or declaration of the penalty and others obstinately persevering in manifest grave sin are not to be admitted to holy communion.

But this canon says the priest may not admit such people to communion, not that the priest must admit anyone who does not meet these criteria to communion.
If, hypothetically, I walked up to the priest just before Mass, and told him that I had committed some grave sin and had not yet repented of it in Confession, but the sin is private, known only to me and the priest, it seems common sense to me that if I then approach to receive communion during Mass, the priest should deny me. Even if I did not tell him the particulars of the sin, but merely that it was grave or mortal, it seems common sense that he ought to deny communion to me.
I would very much like to see the reasoning from a trained canon lawyer as to how the law as written requires priests, especially pastors, to give communion to someone they know is in unrepentant mortal sin as long as the sin isn't publicly manifest. Or, if that is incorrect, are there any canon lawyers who say that the priest in my hypothetical scenario is permitted to refuse someone communion?

Seems related to https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/103935.

@Matthew I asked this question because of a discussion on that question, so they are certainly related.

Oh, wow, since I wasn't tagged (recently) in that discussion, I missed that it had become so... involved.

I'll have to do more digging; I've found some commentary on 915 which suggests why it cannot always be used (i.e. why someone shouldn't be denied in certain cases) which is related. As a thought exercise, think about if it's known only to you and the priest, what will turning you away from communion imply to everyone else?

@eques certainly protecting the good of my soul from profaning the Eucharist is more important than my good name, so if everyone else can infer from my being turned away, so be it. The priest hasn't violated the seal of confession, either, since I told him outside of the sacrament.

@jaredad7 off hand, I can only state the Church doesn't operate on that framework, so there must be more details than your analysis shows.

If the Pastor or Priest knows that the person committed a grave sin, why did he not encourage or help the person to confess his sins and do penance and receive a absolution,so that he can be worthy to receive communion. It would appear that the Pastor is negligent of his pastoral duty.

@jongricafort I agree that a pastor who does not encourage repentance is negligent in his pastoral duty, but it is also conceivable that a pastor has diligently encouraged the person to repent, but still knows that the person has not yet repented, especially if the person has told them so.


According to current Canon Law, is a pastor permitted to deny communion to someone he privately knows to be in a state of grave sin?

Canon Law norms must be in harmony with action of Jesus and the Gospel.
More than the Canon Law, the Priest must follow and imitate Jesus Christ in His words and actions.
Did Jesus teaches the Apostles to deny the Eucharist? No!
Did Jesus gave the Eucharist to Judas despite knowing Judas is in the state of sins? Yes

CITATION CITATION

https://www.catholic.com/magazine/online-edition/why-did-jesus-give-judas-communion
If the Priest is merciful, the direct answer is No!, as instead of denying he will lift-up the soul at that very moment to the mercy of God.
Canon Law like Canon915 in this Time of Mercy must be interpreted according to the lens of Mercy and not to the lens of Justice.
This is where the clash between the Traditionalist and Vatican II Teachings are seen in conflict.
If one listen to the voice of the likes Cdl.Burke,Ab.Chaput, Bishop Strickland, etc., these Bishops are using the lens of Justice, and openly express their position, that they will deny communion.
On the other side, the three Supreme Pontiff had shown to interpret Canon915 using the lens of Mercy, and showed and expressed that they wont deny the eucharist.
This is like drawing the line, if I am a Priest and Bishop who uphold my oath of fidelity and obedience to the Magisterium headed by the Pope, will I listen to the voice of the likes of Cdl.Burke or will I follow the inspirations of St.John Paul II, Pope Benedict XVI and now Pope Francis who repeatedly said, he wont deny the eucharist.
https://www.ncronline.org/news/vatican/pope-francis-says-he-has-never-denied-communion-warns-against-politicizing-eucharist
Priest are guided by Canon Law in the reception of the holy eucharist, but all Priest are not the Supreme Interpreter of Canon Law.
Therefore, a Priest in good state of mind, will always follow the inspiration of the Supreme Interpreter and Legislator of Canon Law, and prudently won't go against the Supreme Pontiff.
How about the gospel?
The gospel showed that Jesus and the Father wont deny bread, metaphorically related to the holy eucharist, the holy bread.

Ask, Seek, Knock
…8For everyone who asks receives; he who seeks finds; and to him who knocks, the door will be opened. 9 Which of you, if his son asks for bread, will give him a stone? 10Or if he asks for a fish, will give him a snake?… -Matthew7:8-9

We can see that a sinner who made an effort to attend a Holy Mass, and took the courage to line up to receive holy communion, are seeking the help and mercy of God.
A Priest must follow the gospel, and so, if the gospel teaches that Jesus and God the Father wont deny the needed bread, then,if a Priest wants to imitate Jesus Christ the Eternal High Priest, then that Priest, must also not deny the holy eucharist.
No Priest or Pastor can deny the Holy Eucharist to a perceived sinner approaching the holy Communion or the Throne of Grace.
Why?
In the case on the issue of politicians supporting abortions, no Priest have the clear faculties to see the state of soul approaching the holy Communion.
Why?
What if, at that very moment God pour out His merciful graces to that perceived sinners?
The Gospel is clear, Jesus and the Father won't deny giving bread to those who seek God.
Canon915 is subjective, it cannot be implemented without pastoral accompaniment first, to enable the Priest better discern the state of soul of a perceived sinners.
Amoris Laetetia, Politicians supporting abortions, homosexuals, SSU, etc.
are the several issues where Canon915 is tested, and Pope Francis the Supreme Interpreter and Legislator of Canon Law teaches, he won't dent the holy Eucharist to anyone who approach the Throne of Grace.
Likewise, St. John Paul II and Pope Benedict XVI had celebrated Holy Masses to politicians supporting abortions, showing three Supreme Pontiff harmonious interpretation of Canon Law, that No Pastor can deny the communion.
In, closing, we are now living in this Time of Mercy,and all the Priest, Bishops, and Cardinals who are opposing the inspiration of the Holy Spirit starting in Vatican II Council, St.John XXIII. St.Pope Paul VI, St.John Paul II, Pope Benedict XVI and now Pope Francis, to preach and magnify the mercy of God on all sinners like couples in irregular union, LGBT, SSU, politicians supporting abortions, etc., we all must not listen to schismatic voices of Priest,Bishops and Cardinals.
We all must follow and support the inspiration of the Holy Spirit to Vatican II Popes, to preach and magnify the mercy of God and not His Justice.Remember, Mercy is the Justice of God.
James2:13

Private sin is not a subject of Canon 915. The time of mercy vs time of justice rings of Modernist heresy.

Is it merciful to act like sinners in unrepentant sin have no problem before God, or is more merciful to put them under church discipline (including denying communion)?

@eques Sounds schismatic to me. St. Faustina writings magnifying the mercy of God supports Pope Francis inspiration, while the schismatic bishops and Cardinals shouting condemnation on the likes of Biden and Pelosi, are the Modern Day Judases of our times.

@curiousdannii Who is worthy more worthy to receive the holy Eucharist the manifest schismatic Trads and manifest Judas Priest, Bishops and Cardinals openly opposing and rejecting PF approved magisterial teachings or the politicians supporting abortions by virtue of their mandate?

Is Pope Francis very own words, saying "He won't deny communion" not enough citation to CSE? The Admin on this site must be reminded that Pope Francis is the Supreme Pontiff, the Supreme Legislator and Interpreter of Canon Law, and his open statement is the GUIDING statement, the citation that clearly supports my answer.

@jongricafort until Pope Francis brings canon law in line with his personal commitment never to deny communion to anyone, his personal commitment really has no bearing on the question. Canon law is under his power, and if he wanted to legally compel priests to give communion to anyone who approached, he could do it.

@jongricafort Your rhetorical question doesn't seem to have anything to do with the subject matter of this question. There are other questions about Catholics supporting progressive politics, but this is not that question, so I suggest you take your thoughts to the appropriate questions.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
